# How can I copy data in GCP from a public Cloud Storage bucket to my own bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nlp

Problem

When following the GCP Automl Vision quickstart(https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/edge-quickstart), 
I'm trying to copy sample images into my own bucket, using the following code in google cloud shell:

gsutil -m cp -R gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/ gs://${BUCKET}/img/

However I get the following error:

CommandException: "cp" command does not support provider-only URLs.

How can it be resolved?

Thanks very much.

Giovanni

Comment: I had no problems with your exact command on my system. What version of gsutil are you using? Update if necessary. Are you running gstutil standalone or as part of the SDK? Update your question with more details. Narrow the command to a single file transfer that fails. Then add the `-d` option to debug one transfer.

Comment: What's the result of the command `echo $BUCKET`? Is this print your bucket name?

Comment: Hi,

@John Hanley & guillaume blaquiere

Thanks very much for the replies! With your replies I was able to solve the problem. Thanks again.

Giovanni

Comment: @Giovanni, since you found a solution with the suggestions provided by John Hanley and guillaume blaquiere, could you post it as an answer so other users, who might have the same issue, find it more easily?

Answer (score 7):

This might occur when your BUCKET_NAME value is blank (check using echo $BUCKET_NAME).

set a value for BUCKET_NAME using

```
export BUCKET_NAME=<bucketName>
```

check the value using :

```
echo $BUCKET_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

**Do not use {} in bucket name**

```
BUCKET_NAME = 'my_bucket'
```

in place of

```
gsutil cp some.txt gs://${BUCKET_NAME}
```

**Error message**
    CommandException: "cp" command does not support provider-only URLs.

**Use Below -- remove curly bracket {}**

```
gsutil cp some.txt gs://$BUCKET_NAME
```

**Output**

```
Copying file://sa.enc [Content-Type=application/octet-stream]...
/ [1 files][  2.4 KiB/  2.4 KiB]                                                
Operation completed over 1 objects/2.4 KiB.
```

Comment: This helped me when running in a script. I got the ${} from the documentation and it seems working when executing directly in cloudbuild as part of args.